# What does WindowsDX mean; what does WindowsGL mean, and the basic difference

Tags: windows, operating-system, versions

I want to install some libraries, namely MonoGame, on my Windows10 computer.  There appear to be a WindowsDX and WindowsGL (or DesktopGL).  What is the basic difference between references to WindowsDX and GL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume WindowsGL refers to the Windows implementation of OpenGL.  OpenGL is an open, industry standard library and interface for using/programming graphics hardware.

WindowsDX probably refers to Windows DirectX.  DirectX is a suite of libraries for multimedia programming in general, including D3D for interfacing with graphics hardware, in particular.

The capabilities are comparable, but the interfaces differ.

Windows supports both, with OpenGL possibly being handled by translating commands into their DirectX equivalents at some level of the driver stack.  I don't think any non-Windows platforms support DirectX.